# The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type. Can't declare Number as number

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

I have an array of objects

```
student = [{
rollNo: Number,
name: String,
dateOfJoining: Number
}];
```

Now I'm trying to sort my array inside my function using this code.

```
students(){
for( let item of res.data){
this.event.push({
        name: item.name,
        rollNo: item.rollNO,
        date: item.joining,
      });
}
this.student.sort((val1, val2) => {return val2.dateOfJoining - val1.dateOfJoining});
}
```

But I'm getting the error "The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type."
I know it's because my dateOfJoining is 'Number' and not 'number'.

But I can't write it as 'number' because then I get the error "'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Number` is a constructor for the JavaScript number type. This is not the value that you intend.

```
interface Student {
  rollNo: number;
  name: string;
  dateOfJoining: number;
}

student: Student[] = [{
  ...
}];
```

Note that this will require a default value for `student`, but an empty array will also work, e.g.

```
student = Student[] = [];
student.push({ rollNo: 1, name: 'Andrew', dateOfJoining: 2 });
```

At this point you will have to fill in `student` with the actual values which should be numbers and strings.

Comment: I created the interface as you suggested and then I'm also not able to push values inside my array from the response I'm getting from my API but still, I'm getting the left-hand side error

Comment: @harshitraghav can you add the code for how you push values to the array?

Comment: If you push and never assign values directly, you should assign an empty list to `student` first